# Unregistered user - how can I return to my question to select an answer? SO has forgotten I was the questioner

Tags: support, edits, answers, unregistered-users

SO recognised me yesterday and I gave my email, to become a unregistered user and ask the question.  But somehow today its not tracked that I asked that question, so I can't edit the question, tick an answer and more importantly say thank you. How can I do this? I went to login page but that creates a registered user, and doesn't link it with the unregistered user even if I use the same email and username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact team@stackoverflow.com and have them merge the accounts.

Comment: I demand that you stop being faster than me!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you contact team@stackoverflow.com and they should be able to assist moving the question under your profile once you sign up for one (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 1):

You can send an email to team@stackoverflow.com and ask them to connect you with that account (if you can provide information that it is really you)